# Windows form, display dynamic google map instead of static map in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, plot, leaflet

I am trying to display a dynamic google map on a windows form in .NET

I have succeeded in implementing a windows form asking a request on google map as followed :

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void find_data_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string street = txt_street.Text;
        string city = txt_city.Text;
        try
        {
            StringBuilder queryaddress = new StringBuilder();
            queryaddress.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=");
            if (street != string.Empty)
            {
                queryaddress.Append(street + "," + "+");
            }
            if (city != string.Empty)
            {
                queryaddress.Append(city + "," + "+");
            }
            webBrowser1.Navigate(queryaddress.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

Then I succeeded in having a staticmap with google api with multiple markers doing this :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder queryaddress = new StringBuilder();
            queryaddress.Append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=63.259591,-144.667969&zoom=6&size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C62.107733,-145.541936&markers=size:tiny%7Ccolor:green%7CDelta+Junction,AK&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:0xFFFF00%7Clabel:C%7CTok,AK&key=myApiKey");
            webBrowser1.Navigate(queryaddress.ToString());                               
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

What I would like to have is the same output as the staticmap with multiple markers but with the interaction offers as in google map like in the first code portions.

I use to code with R and python, using the library leaflet to ease the implementation.

I don't know how to do multiple plot markers on interactive maps in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a turnkey solution with tutorials at this address :
http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/